# Are the **likelihood** in Bayes Rule the same to the one in [Maximum likelihood estimation][1]?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

"Think Bayes by Allen B. Downey" 
 calls the `P(X | A)` part **likelihood** in Bayes Rule

\begin{align}
 P( A | X ) = & \frac{ P(X | A) P(A) } {P(X) } \\\\[5pt]
\end{align}

Are the **likelihood** here the same to the one in [Maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the likelihood is the likelihood. You sometimes see likelihood defined only up to a multiplicative constant (as Fisher did) but that doesn't harm either of those applications if you are consistent in how you deal with it.

Unfortunately, by asking a yes-or-no question to which the answer is "yes" there's not much more to say. If the answer had been no, at least the difference would need to be explained.